# Convert static params to array and use with lambda WHERE

Tags: c#

I have 3 overload methods:

```
public static bool DoesRecordExist(string keyColumn, string keyValue, DataTable dt) {
 if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0) {
  bool exists = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(r => string.Equals(SafeTrim(r[keyColumn]), keyValue, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).Any();
  return exists;
 } else {
  return false;
 }
}

public static bool DoesRecordExist(string keyColumn1, string keyColumn2, string keyValue1, string keyValue2, DataTable dt) {
 if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0) {
  bool exists = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(r => string.Equals(SafeTrim(r[keyColumn1]), keyValue1, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) && string.Equals(SafeTrim(r[keyColumn2]), keyValue2, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).Any();
  return exists;
 } else {
  return false;
 }
}

public static bool DoesRecordExist(string keyColumn1, string keyColumn2, string keyColumn3, string keyValue1, string keyValue2, string keyValue3, DataTable dt) {
 if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0) {
  bool exists = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(r => string.Equals(SafeTrim(r[keyColumn1]), keyValue1, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) && string.Equals(SafeTrim(r[keyColumn2]), keyValue2, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) && string.Equals(SafeTrim(r[keyColumn3]), keyValue3, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).Any();
  return exists;
 } else {
  return false;
 }
}
```

These all work as expected, and as you can see, all 3 are identical, just with increasing numbers of params and corresponding `where` clause arguments. And now I need to add yet another overload with 5 key/value pairs. Clearly this is getting silly.

How can I convert all these overloads into a single function in which I simply pass in a `Hashtable` of key-value pairs (or some other collection that makes equal or better sense)?

### Duplicate feedback

I believe my question is different to [this proposed duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508087/check-if-any-item-in-a-list-matches-any-item-in-another-list). I am looking for an approach in which I can pass in a Hashtable, array, or some collection-based approach for n number of key-value params and related where clauses.

Comment: `dt.AsEnumerable().Any(r => kvps.All(kvp => r[kvp.Key].Equals(kvp.Value)));` ? Kvps is just an ienumerable of KeyValuePair<string,object>, this logic asks "is there any row where all entries in a set of columns c have corresponding values v

Comment: Might want to stick your safe trim in there too, but I'm not sure how that makes sense for ints..

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using an extension method with a `Dictionary<string, string>` parameter:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool DoesRecordExist(this DataTable dt, Dictionary<string, string> KeysAndValues)
    {
        if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            var rows = dt.AsEnumerable();
            foreach (var key in KeysAndValues.Keys)
            {
                rows = rows.Where(row => string.Equals(row[key], KeysAndValues[key], StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
            }
            return rows.Any();
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Which you can then use like this:

```
var keysAndValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
keysAndValues.Add("FirstName", "John");
keysAndValues.Add("LastName", "Doe");
var dt = ... // your DataTable
Console.WriteLine(dt.DoesRecordExist(keysAndValues));
```

or with an initializer:

```
var keysAndValues = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "FirstName", "John"} ,
    { "LastName", "Doe" }
};
var dt = ... // your DataTable
Console.WriteLine(dt.DoesRecordExist(keysAndValues));
```

And finally, you may need to use `row[key].ToString()` or `row[key] as string` instead of just `row[key]`.